# How to generate API docs with openapi-generator.tech

Tags: go, openapi-generator-cli

I am playing around with https://openapi-generator.tech/ and I have an example `openapi.yaml` file:

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0

info:
  title: Sample API
  description: My amazing description.
  version: 0.0.9

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/v1
    description: My amazing server description.

paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of all users.
      description: My amazing /users endpoint description.
      responses:
        "200":
          description: (OK) A JSON array of user objects.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
```

I have tried the following generation command:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -g go-gin-server --global-property=apiDocs=true -i ./openapi.yaml
```

both with, and without the `--global-property=apiDocs=true` part. Neither case generated an `/api`, `/doc`, or `/docs` endpoint.

What am I doing wrong?

Note that the server runs fine, i.e., I can `curl` the endpoints specified in the `yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the server stub generator `go-gin-server` supports adding this type of endpoint.  If you look at the [routers template](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/0d1e31324b35463f087b620bedea6da961323f62/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/go-gin-server/routers.mustache#L51) that this generator uses you can see that no config option will generate an `/api`, `/doc` or `/docs` endpoint unless you have defined it in your spec.

It's not clear to me exactly what you are expecting from this endpoint, but you could define one of these endpoints in your spec and implement the behavior you would like, or you could [customize the template](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#user-defined-templates) to automatically add this endpoint during code generation

Comment: I would expect it to auto-generate the swagger docs for the API, since the `yaml` file provides all the information required, no?

Comment: Perhaps there are some server stub code generators that support that, but it appears `go-gin-server` does not.  It probably wouldn't be hard to implement on your own though, there are a number of documentation generators you could hook in to your build process in the same place you will hook in the server stub code generation: https://nordicapis.com/7-open-source-openapi-documentation-generators/